# Permission issues when trying to run XAMPP on Mac OS with OpenCart

Tags: macos, apache, permissions, xampp, opencart

I have followed the other documentation currently online regarding MacOS and permission issues when trying to run the opencart on the server. I have it working up until clicking the upload link where I get the below  3 errors. I have tried to utilize the terminal to fix the permission via the following commands below. I have also manually gone into every file mentioned in the errors and clicked "get info" to change the permission for profile "everyone" to Read and Write instead of just read. However, none of these have altered the errors. I am wondering if I need to go into the files mentioned in the errors and write code to ignore the use of these files as I do not need it for my use case. I am trying to practise Application testing in a course so am only need the environment to run in order to populate the test case results. Thanks!

sudo chown -R _www:_www /Applications/XAMPP

chmod -R 0777 /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs

sudo chmod -R 755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Cache/FilesystemCache.php on line 50

Warning: file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/storage/logs/error.log): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/library/log.php on line 36

Warning: file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/storage/logs/error.log): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/library/log.php on line 36Unable to create the cache directory (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/storage/cache/template/c3).: in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Cache/FilesystemCache.php on line 53

Comment: First verify that the `system/storage/logs/` directory exists, and then do a quick test if you manually create the error.log file by `touch error.log`, does this warning still show up if you reload the page? If yes then you have a new file permissions problem in MacOS, so you should see the answer to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/permissions-for-new-files-in-shared-directory